# Setting interval timer to select value in React.js

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

I have a function that I want to fire every x seconds based on how many seconds the user chooses from a dropdown.

The function (which works when I just type in a number)

```
refreshNames(){
    setInterval(this.getNames, 1000);
  };
```

The JSX:

```
<select id="timerInterval">
    <option value="5">1 sec</option>
    <option value="10">2 sec</option>
    <option value="15">3 sec</option>
</select>
```

If I replace 1000 with {timer}, how can I then set {timer} to the selected value?

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the timer value in local state of the react component. As the value will be changed by user, the interval will change. You need to handle onChange event of the select.

```
this.state = {
  timerInterval: 1000 //default value
}

handleIntervalChange = (e) => {
  const val = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value;  //not sure if this is correct but somehow you can get the value
  this.setState({timerInterval: val})
}

<select id="timerInterval" onChange={this.handleIntervalChange}>
...
</select>

refreshNames(){
    setInterval(this.getNames, this.state.timerInterval);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the running interval and then restart it with a new interval if you want to use `setInterval`. You could instead probably use `setTimeout` and call the timeout from within the function again to `simulate` a `setInterval` like

```js
class App extends React.Component {
   state = {
      timerInterval: 1000
   }
   getNames = () => {
    console.log('names');
    setTimeout(this.getNames, this.state.timerInterval);
   }
   componentDidMount() {
      setTimeout(this.getNames, this.state.timerInterval);
   }
   handleChange = (e) => {
      const val = e.target.value;  
      console.log('interval', val*1000);
      this.setState({timerInterval: val*1000})
   }
   render() {
    return (
      <select id="timerInterval" onChange={this.handleChange}>
        <option value="1">1 sec</option>
        <option value="2">2 sec</option>
        <option value="3">3 sec</option>
     </select>
    )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```